# What is the cardinality of the inverse image of a point under the map $β(ℕ^2)→β(ℕ)^2$?

Tags: general-topology, set-theory, boolean-algebra, compactification

I will write $β$ for the [Stone-Čech compactification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93%C4%8Cech_compactification). Let $p$ be the canonical map $β(ℕ^2)→β(ℕ)^2$. Let $(u,v) ∈ β(ℕ)^2$. If $u$ or $v$ is in $ℕ$, then $p^{-1}(u,v)$ is a singleton. Otherwise, $p^{-1}(u,v)$ contains at least two points:

*Proof.* Let $(x_i)_{i∈I}$ and $(y_j)_{j∈J}$ be two nets converging toward $u$ and $v$, respectively. Let $A := \{(i,j)∈I×J\,|\,x_i<y_j\}$ and let $B := \{(i,j)∈I×J\,|\,x_i>y_j\}$. Let $a$ be a limit point of $(x_i,y_j)_{(i,j)∈A}$ and let $b$ be a limit point of $(x_i,y_j)_{(i,j)∈B}$. Then $p(a) = p(b) = (u,v)$ but $a≠b$.

If $u=v$, I can show that there are at least $3$ points using the same technique. I tried to extend this method by showing that the adherence of the net $([x_i:y_j])_{i,j} ⊆ ℝP^1$ contains many points but this is actually false.

What is the cardinality of $p^{-1}(u,v)$ (assuming AC and CH)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cardinality of $p^{-1}(u,v)$ depends on the particular ultrafilters $u$ and $v$.  It can be any finite number (since you've assumed CH) or $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$.  Smaller infinite cardinals are impossible because every infinite closed subset of $\beta\mathbb N$ (or $\beta(\mathbb N^2)$) includes a copy of $\beta\mathbb  N$ and therefore has cardinality $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$.

Details about the connection between the cardinality of $p^{-1}(u,v)$ and the combinatorial properties of $u$ and $v$ are in a paper I wrote with Gugu Moche, available at [http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~ablass/moche.pdf](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/%7Eablass/moche.pdf) .

Comment: Thanks for that! I wrote an additional question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4564619/why-does-every-infinite-closed-subset-of-%ce%b2%e2%84%95-contains-a-copy-of-%ce%b2%e2%84%95) about the fact that every infinite closed subset of $βℕ$ contains a copy of $βℕ$.